# some of the logs are missing with TimedRotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, logging

I need your help in solving this problem. So I am using Python's timedrotatingfilehandler lib to append logs for 24 hours in a log file and then rotate the log file. This works as expected but every time I run my script, timedrotatingfilehandler only logs till certain point. For example: If I have 10 log statement, each run only logs till 5 and then nothing gets logged in the log file. Appending happens correctly though. Not sure whats happening. Here is the python code:

```
#Configuring logger
LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def config_Logs():
    # format the log entries
    global LOG
    formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] : {%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('collecting_logs.log', 
                                   when='h', interval=24, backupCount=0)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    LOG.addHandler(handler)
    LOG.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

I am calling config_Logs() at the beginning of the script.

Comment: This looks fine. It's probably something else in your code causing it.

Comment: I finally figured out the issue. The issue was related to remote ssh from my python script. timedrotatingfilehandler doesn't log once the control comes back to the script after sshing to remote, thats when it stops logging the log.